# why won't "toByteArray()" execute?

Tags: android, serialization, arrays, save, objectoutputstream

I've been trying to figure this out for hours and it's soo frustrating!
I am serializing a 'hashtable', which is the object that I am passing to this method
'saveDataToDisk(Object o)', I tested this out in a regular java project and it executes the 'toByteArray()' correctly, but in Android it always goes into the catch whenever it hits toByteArray()... any ideas? Thank you in advance.

```
public static byte[] saveDataToDisk(Object o)
{
    // Storing the data into byte streams.
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    try
    {
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
        out.writeObject(o);
        out.close();
        // Get the bytes of the serialized object
        byte[] buf = bos.toByteArray();

        return buf;
    }
    catch (IOException ioe)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the exception you get?

Comment: No exception, i return NULL, when i tried to do 'ioe.printStackTrace()', nothing printed. Does anyone have an alternative to this if i can't seem to resolve this? >: P

Comment: if you put a breakpoint inside the catch statement, you should be able to inspect the ioe variable. or place it above, and step over until it hits the catch.

EDIT: also, While you are there, check the size of your bos variable. if it has data it should be > 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to execute your use case, seems to work for me. 
Refer to the code below
I get a byte array : [-84, -19, 0, 5, 116, 0, 2, 72, 105]

```
public class WriteObject extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_1);
    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        String s = "Hi";
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            byte[] b = WriteObject.saveDataToDisk(s);
            Log.i("", b.toString());

        }

    });
}
public static byte[] saveDataToDisk(Object o){
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buf = null;
    try{
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
        out.writeObject(o);
        out.close();
        buf = bos.toByteArray();
    }catch (IOException ioe){
        Log.e("", ioe.toString(),ioe);
    }
    return buf;
}

}
```

Comment: WOW... the answer is, I can't put the return statement inside of the "try" block... i never knew that.

Comment: @ObjectiveC-InLearning, yes, you can,

Comment: are you able to explain why my code above didn't work, but when i moved the 'return buf' outside it did? You're probably right, but i'm just curious.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](http://www.javafaq.nu/java-article236.html)

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
oos.writeObject(obj);
oos.flush();
oos.close();
bos.close();
byte [] data = bos.toByteArray();
return data;
```

So you may want to try out.flush()